# At boot in kubuntu open a shell and run a script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I everybody

after boot if is possible i want to open a shell and run a simple c++ program automatically ! its difficult ?

```
airone@airone:~$ sudo ./provaccc
[sudo] password for airone: 
Reading From : /dev/input/event2 (Sycreader RFID Technology Co., Ltd SYC     ID&IC USB Reader)
Ingresso Palestra: SUCCESS
```

its possible ?
thanks a lot

Comment: The right thing is generally to use your OS's process supervision system to run your software (and, if you prefer, restart it if it exits). Depending on the exact version of Ubuntu, this will be either Upstart or systemd.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not directly programming related and is better posed to the StackExchange site of [**Unix & Linux**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: (I'd argue, btw, that this is more a question about configuring your OS than it is about developing software -- nothing about running a program automatically on boot is specific to the topic of *developing* programs).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always include it in some of the common "starters", most probably in ~/.bashrc. The one single important thing would be to suppress the stdout prior to putting it over there. You have to adjust its permissions as well, in order not to be asked for the sudo password. With the limited information I have, I presume it should be something like:

```
chown <user>:<group> airone
chmod 755 provaccc
echo 'bash <full path>/provaccc' > /dev/null >> ~./bashrc
```

Test it with sourcing ~/.bashrc:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Of course there could be multiple adjustments, but I am sure you can work these out.